# Boxes from previous tab overlaid on current tab

Tags: nvidia, graphics, dell

I'm not sure how to describe the problem other than with a screenshot, so here's one:

[image: Screenshot with boxes from IRC tab overlaid on Discord tab]

Discord is the active tab in this picture; IRC is the tab I was previously on.

This is on a Dell XPS 15-7590. The "Additional Drivers" settings page says:
NVIDIA Corporation: TU117M [GeForce GTX 1650 Mobile / Max-Q]
This device is using the recommended driver.

The most important thing I want to know is whether this is likely to be fixable or I'll need to just return the machine for one that has better Ubuntu support.